# Cypress iterate over the table and click on the matching text passed from gherkin file

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I am new to cypress and have a scenario where i need to select 'text2' from below table which is under a view, 'text2' is the value from feature file.

```
<table>
  <tr .............>
     <td ..........>
        <div  ....>
           <input class= ' ' ..... value='text1'>
         </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr .............>
     <td ..........>
        <div  ....>
           <input class= ' ' ..... value='text2'>
         </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

i tried with
`cy.get('table tr').find('td').contains('text2').click()` its not working,
Any Suggestions would be of great help, Thanks.

Comment: To select the contents of an `input` element use `select()`, not `click()`

Comment: Tried with select(), but didn't work, its not able to get the value 'text2', error "Timed out retrying: Expected to find content: 'text2' within the element: [ <td>, 5 more... ] but never did."

Comment: what do you mean by select ? do you want to highlight it or copy the values? If it's a click you need to do you try `.click({force: true})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, this is actually a bit tricky.

If you follow this Cypress example [Find the input[type='submit'] by value](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Find-the-input-type-39-submit-39-by-value),

then your inputs **must** have the `type='submit'` attribute for `contains()` to work.

```html
<div id="main">
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>name</label>
      <input name="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>age</label>
      <input name="age" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit the form!" />
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
// yields input[type='submit'] element then clicks it
cy.get('form').contains('submit the form!').click()
```

However, `type='submit'` produces **buttons** on the web page.

---

If you want input boxes (type='text' which is the default if not specified), you cannot use `.contains()`. You can access the value of a with `.invoke('val')`.

Sadly however, `.invoke('val')` does not pinpoint the exact element in the same way `.contains()` does. It simply gets the text value of the **first** input and returns the text, not the element (so you can't click it).

The best way I found is to construct a selection function inside a `then()`

```
cy.get('table tr td input')
  .then($inputs => {                           // pass in all inputs
    return Array.from($inputs)                 // convert to array
      .find(input => input.value === 'text2')  // use Array.find() to pick the element
  })
  .should('have.value', 'text2')  // in case 'text2' does not exist
  .click()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just select the element that contains the test:

```
cy.contains('text2').click();
```